# Android App fatal exception main:

Tags: java, android

I have a new app built with Cocos2dx and Eclipse. After cleaning and building in Eclipse the Android application force-closes with the following manifest and LogCat.

```
11-25 14:38:15.483: E/AndroidRuntime(2792): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.RWF.Wheels5Fun2/com.RWF.Wheels5Fun2.Wheels5Fun2}:  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.RWF.Wheels5Fun2.Wheels5Fun2
```

Here's the manifest:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.RWF.Wheels5Fun2"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"/>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />

    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/spinpressed">

        <activity android:name=".Wheels5Fun2"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:configChanges="orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
                      android:smallScreens="true"
                      android:anyDensity="true"
                      android:normalScreens="true"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    </manifest>
```

Comment: Just to get this straight: you have a package "com.RWF.Wheels5Fun2" and the main Activity is "Wheels5Fun2"? Is the package name com.RWF? or com.RWF.Wheels5fun2?

Comment: The package name is com.RWF.Wheels5Fun2.  and the main Activity is Wheels5Fun2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your error message says "you forgot to define Activity in Manifest file"

Please! update you manifest file with correct Package and Activity name.

**YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME** <-- change the name here, and run again.

---

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.RWF.Wheels5Fun2"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"/>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />

    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/spinpressed">

        <activity android:name="com.RWF.YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:configChanges="orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
                      android:smallScreens="true"
                      android:anyDensity="true"
                      android:normalScreens="true"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    </manifest>
```